# Prove that $U = \left \{ f(x) = a*\sin(x+b) | \; a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is a sub space

Tags: linear-algebra

Where $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the vector space of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

I have no idea how to show that $U$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @amsmath subspace**

Comment: do you mean "linear subspace"?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Obviously. OP speaks about closedness under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two arbitrary elements $f_1(x) = a_1 \sin(x + b_1)$ and $f_2(x) = a_2 \sin(x+b_2)$ in $U$ for some $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

We wish to show that $f_1(x) + f_2(x) \in U$.
\begin{align}
f_1(x)+f_2(x) ={}& a_1 \sin(x + b_1) + a_2 \sin(x+b_2) \\
={}& a_1 (\sin(x) \cos(b_1) + \cos(x) \sin(b_1)) + a_2 (\sin(x) \cos(b_2) + \cos(x)\sin(b_2)) \\
={}& (a_1 \cos(b_1)  + a_2 \cos(b_2)) \sin(x) + (a_1 \sin(b_1) + a_2 \sin(b_2)) \cos(x) \\
={}& k_1 \sin(x) + k_2 \cos(x) \\
\end{align}

where $k_1 = a_1 \cos(b_1)  + a_2 \cos(b_2)$, and $k_2 = a_1 \sin(b_1) + a_2 \sin(b_2)$.

It is possible to go from the last line to something of the form $A \sin(x + \phi)$. You can look up the auxiliary angle method [here](https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php). This will help you with showing closure under addition. To show closure under multiplication, try showing $\alpha f_1(x) \in U$.